# Site Audit using Python and Scrapy

Tags: python

I'm working on a small project using Python and Scrapy ( I'm new in Python coming from PHP World ),
I'm crawling a website and would like to do an Audit to check if I have 404-pages and also if I have a long title...
**I would like to create a list like that  ( expected result ) :**

```
{
    '404' : [
        'url 1',
        'url 2',
        'url 3'
    ],
    'longTitle' : [
        'url 1',
        'url 2',
        'url 3'
    ]
}
```

My code :

```
def parse_item(self, response):
        errors = {}
        title = response.css('title::text').get()
        if(len(title) > 70):
            errors['longTitle'] = response.css('title::text').get()
```

Comment: What `response.css('title::text').get()˛` returns you ?

Comment: Text between title tag @programer angel

Comment: I want to know just how i can have the expected result. Don't worry about the values